# Will I be able to get CSQ after the completion of the diploma?

Tags: immigration, canada

I'm currently working as software developer in a company based in Europe and have MSc degree in an engineering discipline. I plan to take programmer analyst mobile and web application development diploma in the Montreal college of information technology. To make the point clear, My original intention is to settle down in Quebec and eventually, Canada and not the education itself. So, I'm willing to endure even if the quality of the education is modest.

Will I be able to file CSQ after completion of the program? I have scored in DELF B2 above 16/25 in both listening and the speaking section. I also have 1.5 years of working experience in the web development (Java stack).

While I'm aware of the express entry program, I don't have enough points to secure a position there for now. I sincerely hope someone knowledgeable will help me out in this respect.

Comment: Is it a residential program? That is, it's not an online program? One of the requirements is that you spend at least half the time of a diploma living in Quebec.

Comment: This is 8 months program in Quebec. I have question: if I get CSQ via PEQ, will I be able to live in Quebec indefinitely?

Answer (score 2):

As a student in Canada, you are able to apply for both CSQ and PEQ, according to Immigration, Diversité et Inclusion Québec:

> [Applying for a **Certificat de sélection du Québec** (CSQ – Québec selection certificate)](http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/en/informations/peq/index.html)
>
> If you wish to settle in Québec permanently and you are a foreign student, Québec graduate or skilled temporary foreign worker employed in Québec, you can apply for a Certificat de sélection du Québec (CSQ) in the skilled worker class. Note that you must be age 18 or older and plan to settle in Québec with the intention of being gainfully employed.
>
> IMPORTANT: If you are applying for a Certificat de sélection du Québec as a skilled worker, you must choose between the Programme de l’expérience québécoise (PEQ – Québec experience program) and the regular selection program for skilled workers. We provide a [self-assessment questionnaire](http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/en/informations/peq/self-assessment-questionnaire.html) to direct you to the information and forms associated with the program that seems most appropriate in your situation.
>
> **Programme de l’expérience québécoise** (PEQ – Québec experience program) (simplified process)
>
> [PEQ – Québec graduate](http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/en/immigrate-settle/students/stay-quebec/application-csq/students-peq/index.html)
>   This program is aimed at you if you have obtained an eligible Québec diploma, or you are in the process of doing so, and you have an advanced intermediate knowledge of oral French.
>
> **Regular selection program for skilled workers**
>   This program assesses your socio-occupational characteristics based on ten factors and also takes into account the characteristics of your spouse or de facto spouse included in your application.
>
> [**Foreign student in Québec**](http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/en/immigrate-settle/students/stay-quebec/application-csq/students-quebec/index.html)
>   The regular program applies to you if you are pursuing or have successfully completed a study program in Québec.

Comment: Will I be able to live in Quebec with the CSQ indefinitely or there are any hidden catch? Also, will I be able to apply for the Canadian PR with the CSQ or there will be more hidden agendas like to hold a job or hold a job for x months etc? I'm a software dev and positive to get employed but still needs to know the matter properly